# Android studio emulator crashes when i put "." on the field

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm currently trying to make an app that calculates calories for the user, but i don't know why my app keeps crashing when i put "." on the field. When i put only numbers it works with no problems

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="376dp"
        android:layout_height="428dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.461"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.258">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Proteínas(g)"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtNro1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="#C3BEBE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Carboidratos(g)"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtNro2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="#C3BEBE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gorduras(g)"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtNro3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="#C3BEBE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btCalcular"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="Calcular"
            android:text="Calcular" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="O total de calorias é"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResultado"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my main:

```
package com.example.calorias;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText txtNro1;
    private EditText txtNro2;
    private EditText txtNro3;
    private TextView tvResultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtNro1 = findViewById(R.id.txtNro1);
        txtNro2 = findViewById(R.id.txtNro2);
        txtNro3 = findViewById(R.id.txtNro3);
        tvResultado = findViewById(R.id.tvResultado);
    }

    public void Calcular(View view){
        double valor1 = Integer.parseInt(txtNro1.getText().toString());
        double valor2 = Integer.parseInt(txtNro2.getText().toString());
        double valor3 = Integer.parseInt(txtNro3.getText().toString());

        double v1 = (valor1 * 4) ;
        double v2 = (valor2 * 4);
        double v3 = (valor3 * 9);

        tvResultado.setText(String.valueOf(v1 + v2 + v3));
    }

}
```

I used "NumberDecimal" to block the use of anything other than a number or a "."
I also tried a couple of different things i found online, but no luck so far.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Emulator doesn't crash your app does, change the title

Comment: When stuff like this happens, look in the Logcat tab to see what the actual error message is. Most of the time it will tell you pretty clearly which line has an error and what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting decimal numbers don't try to parse them as `Integer`

```
double valor3 = Integer.parseInt(txtNro3.getText().toString());
```

as it will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @LuisTartareli you probably want Double.parseDouble here.  But even that would crash if they types an 'a' or a '*'.  You probably want to catch NumberFormatException and show an error (or do something else reasonable).

Answer (score 0):

It worked, instead of "Integer.parseInt" i used double valor1 = parseDouble(txtNro1.getText().toString());